# Encoding Geolocation data

Tags: neural-networks, feature-engineering, graph-neural-network, graph-embedding

I am working on routing bus from one stop to another, for which Geolocation data inform of latitude and longitude is required. In addition to xy coordinates, distance matrix of locations is also created. How to encode coordinates into NN, encoding them directly does not help as it will affect predictions (which is not required as here xy are use as ids to specify distance between 2 points).

If I replace them with whole numbers it will again affect prediction, I am confused plz help will be much appreciated
regards
Hina Ali[image]

Comment: You can design your graph neural network to have permutation invariance on the index set of your vertices and/or edges. See [Bronstein *et al* 2021](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.13478).

Comment: Thanks I will check it

Comment: on second thought can we treat latitude and longitude as cyclical features, and encode them as date and time

Comment: Lat/long are angles in a spherical coordinate system. I don't understand what it means to encode lat/long into date and time.

Comment: Sorry @Galen for confusion, I am using geolocations as input features in to neural network. (as spatial features)